# ¿Cómo hacer que el form mande la información seleccionada con WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress

¿Cómo hacer que el `form` mande la información seleccionada con WordPress?

Éste es mi código:

```
<p>Nombres <br />
    [text* your-name] </p>

<p>Apellidos <br />
    [text* your-lastname] </p>


<p>Email <br />
    [email* your-email] </p>

<p>Celular <br />
    [number* your-number] </p>

<p>Provincia <br />
    [text* your-provincia] </p>

<p> Tipo de Viaje<br />
<select name="Tipo de Viaje ">
<option>Skip Trip (Fuga)</option>
<option>Universitario</option>
<option>Familiar</option>
<option>Grupo de amigos</option>
<option>Pareja</option>
<option>Otros</option>
[text* your-trip]</select> </p>

<p>Nombre de Institucion o Academia (Requerido para Viajes De Graduación, Skip Trips y Universitarios.)<br />
    [text your-institution] </p>

<p>Destino <br />
    [text* your-destination] </p>




<table>
 <tr><p>
  <td>Fecha</td><br />
   <td><select size="1" name="Fecha">
   <option>Seleccione</option>
   <option value="Verano">Verano</option>
   <option value="Invierno">Invierno</option>
   <option value="Semana Santa">Semana Santa</option>
   <option value="Fin de Semestre">Fin de Semestre</option>
   <option value="Family Weekend">Family Weekend</option>
  <option value="Otra">Otra</option>
   [text your-fecha]</select></td>
   <td colspan="4"></p>
    Si es otra, porfavor especifique
   <input type="date" name="Otra_Fecha" size="20">
   </td>
 </tr>
</table> 

<p>Cantidad de pasajeros<br />
    [number* your-passengers] </p>

<p>Describenos el viaje que deseas realizar con detalles<br />
    [textarea* your-details] </p>

Preguntas o comentarios adicionales<br />
   <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>

[submit "Send"]
```

Comment: Estas usando algún plugin como Contact Forms?

Comment: Parece ser el formato de ContactForm7, pero no entiendo muy bien la pregunta. ¿Quieres coger captar el $_POST que manda el formulario del plugin para enviarla con la función wp_mail();?

Comment: si quiero  que lo que se selecciona en el drop down del form se mande al email

Comment: Podrias reformular la pregunta a ¿Cómo añadir campos extras a un formulario del pluggin ContactForm de WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

Se debe seguir el formato de Contact Form , lo primero que debes de hacer es seguir este proceso: http://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/

Ejemplo :

[select your-option "Verano" "Invierno" "etc"]

Luego en en Tab Mail de Contact Form al editar el formulario : http://contactform7.com/faq/nothing-shows-up-in-the-email-even-after-adding-a-tag-to-the-form/ .

Debes asignar el campo que te genera Contact Form /, es decir el shortcode [your-option]

Answer (score 1):

Como ha aclarado el compañero más arriba, tienes que usar las funciones de `ContactForm7`.

Primero, debes crear correctamente el `dropdown` o `select` con tus opciones:

```
[select fecha "Seleccione" "Verano" "Invierno" "Semana Santa" "Fin de Semestre" "Family Weekend" "Otra"]
```

Entonces donde tienes los shortcode que vas a mandar pones

```
[fecha]
```

Con eso te debería bastar para mostrarte el desplegable y cogerte el valor y enviarlo por email.